# Dynamically generate accessors for subclass properties

Tags: c#, properties, entity-framework-core

i would like to implement a dynamic way of creating entities for EntityFramework Core. Therefore i created a base class which adds some basic functionallity to entities. My goal is to achieve a entity handling which can be done with the entity classes exclusively.

This Example should create a User and set the fields Then it should automatically save the changes:

```cs
new User()
{
    Email = "test123@abc.com",
    PwdHash = "some-hash"
}
```

I already created a base class for that to handle such actions in background:

```cs
    public abstract class Entity<T> where T : Entity<T>
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public static T Find(params object[] keyValues)
        {
            var dc = EntityManager.GetContext();

            return dc.Find<T>(keyValues);
        }

        public static List<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> _condition)
        {
            var dc = EntityManager.GetContext();

            return dc.Set<T>().Where(_condition).ToList();
        }

        public void Delete()
        {
            var dc = EntityManager.GetContext();

            dc.Set<T>().Remove((T)this);
            dc.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Commit() 
        {
            var dc = EntityManager.GetContext();

            dc.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

EntityManager simply maintains a DbContext which is working quite fine.

the Entity class is working quite fine too, but i need a way of getting notified on when a property of the subclass (T) is beeing changed to invoke the "Commit()" method.
Currently i am using the property setter:

```cs
    public class User : Entity<User>
    {
        [Required]
        public string Email { 
            get => _email; 
            set { _email = value; Commit(); }
        }
        private string _email = "";

        [Required]
        public string PwdHash { 
            get => _pwdHash;
            set { _pwdHash = value; Commit(); }
        }
        private string _pwdHash = "";
    }
```

But that is not what i want. I would like to simply create a automated property which gets that Commit method appended by the base class automatically. Is that in anyway possible?

Comment: For such purpose you have to use UoW and Repository pattern (even I don't like that). Otherwise you will turn your model in ActiveRecord pattern which is a not performant when you need to store several records in in one batch. Think about that.

Comment: For short term i now just manually call my Commit() method ... But i dont really know what problem could occur on calling these method automatically

Comment: `foreach (var user in Users) { user.Email = "some"; user.PwdHash = "zzz"}` N * commits. It is a problem.